# BigQuery: Extracting month from date (STRING Type) in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've connected my GA account to Bigquery.

Now, I'm trying to group_by month all visits.

But I'm getting:

```
EXTRACT does not support arguments of type: STRING at [2:3]
```

Because my date column is of type STRING.

```
SELECT
      EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM date) AS Month, SUM(totals.visits) as totalVisits, 
    FROM
      `xxxx.yyyy.ga_sessions_20*`
    GROUP BY date
```

I've tried to CAST it to date:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM CAST(date AS date)) AS Month, SUM(totals.visits) as totalVisits, 
FROM
  `xxx-yyyy.ga_sessions_20*`
GROUP BY date
```

Getting:

> A valid date part name is required but found DATE_TIME_PART at [2:11]
>   Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.

What does it mean?

**Expected result:**

```
| year | month    | total_visits |
|:----:|----------|--------------|
| 2019 |  january | 162626       |
| 2019 | february | 599562       |
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
SELECT
 FORMAT_DATE(CAST(date AS date), '%B'), SUM(totals.visits) as totalVisits, 
FROM
  `xxx.yyyy.ga_sessions_20*`
GROUP BY date
```

Gives error:

```
No matching signature for function FORMAT_DATE for argument types: DATE, STRING. Supported signature: FORMAT_DATE(STRING, DATE) at [2:2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
 FORMAT_DATE('%Y', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date)) AS year, 
 FORMAT_DATE('%B', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date)) AS month, 
 SUM(totals.visits) AS totalVisits, 
FROM 
 `xxx.yyyy.ga_sessions_20*`
GROUP BY year, month
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a number, then the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST(date AS date)) AS Month
```

If you want the full name, then use [`FORMAT()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date):

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE(CAST(date AS date), '%B')
```

I would recommend that you include the year as well.

Comment: Please, see my update. Also, how should I add year?